# Adding an image to replace FA Icon in PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using the wordpress theme Blackfyre, so all the CSS and HTML is already done. I am trying to directly alter the php coding that contains the header and footer.
I have been sucessful in changing the FA Icon to something more reasonable, but would I be able to change it to an img instead? FA currently does not have a Discord icon, and I would like to add my own by using an img.

```
<div id="main_wrapper">
<div class="above-nav container">
    <div class="social-top">
        <?php if ( of_get_option('dribbble') ) { ?> <a class="dribbble" target="_blank" href="<?php  echo esc_url(of_get_option('dribbble_link'));  ?>"><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i> <i class="fa fa-headphones"></i> </a><?php } ?>
        <?php if ( of_get_option('youtube') ) { ?> <a class="youtube" target="_blank" href="<?php echo esc_url(of_get_option('youtube_link'));   ?>"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i> </a><?php } ?>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to replace

```
<i class="fa fa-microphone"></i> <i class="fa fa-headphones"></i>
```

with the img icon link. Any assistance would be appreciated.

It currently looks like the below, but I want to replace the headphones/mic with a discord icon img.

[image: Icons]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just taking a guess here, since you didn't post your CSS. This has worked in the past for me, though.

Get rid of "fa fa-headphones".

```
<i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>
```

Remove the "fa-microphone" to lose the icon, but keep the fa layout.

```
<i class="fa"></i>
```

Insert your image...

```
<i class="fa"><img src="yourimage.png"></i>
```

Style as needed. This can be done either in your CSS file, or inline. For example...

```
<i class="fa" style="height: 15px"><img src="yourimage.png"></i>
```

Comment: Thank you
     <i class="fa" ><img src="image.png" width="20" height="20"></i>

works for me